# Meteor Cordova app unable to connect to remote MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, cordova, meteor

I have an existent Meteor+React application that works with a remote MongoDB. This application connects to the remote database if I run it with the following `.sh` file:

```
DB_URL="mongodb://..."

MONGO_URL=$DB_URL \
meteor run --settings config/settings.json
```

But if I try to run a Cordova application it always connects to the local MongoDB and ignores any configurations. I'm trying it this way:

```
DB_URL="mongodb://..."

MONGO_URL=$DB_URL \
meteor run ios-device --verbose --settings config/settings.json
```

How could I setup a MongoDB url for Cordova app properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be experiencing [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5973) issue.

Try with `meteor shell` (as a second instance) to see if the database is accesible from the server. If you can then it's a DDP problem, set a ROOT_URL environment variable for the server instance and try again.